# Remove last char in a string for each row in pandas df

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe with column `keys`, I need to remove the last character from each string.

```
id       keys     
123      "https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv/a46533/"
124      "https://www.bazaar.com/entertainment/tv/a46533/"
```

Currently, I am trying to create a function that would return a clean string and I would apply the function to df later. I tried the following:

```
url_test = "https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv/"

def clean_string(url):
    for string in url:
        new_string = string[:-1]
        return new_string
clean_string(url_test)
```

It returns an empty string. And I want it to return `"url_test = "https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv"`

Answer (score 14):

You can use pandas [string accessor methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str)

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd 
test = pd.Series([
    "https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv/a46533/",
    "https://www.bazaar.com/entertainment/tv/a46533/"])
test = test.str[:-1]
```

will trim the last character from the string. This allows you to operate on the entire column rather than one row at a time.

Comment: For newbs like me :) rem that a "dataframe column" is a Series. Therefore what tomjn shows works perfectly with dataframe as in: df["reference"] = df["reference"].str[:-4] where "reference" is my string dataframe column, from which I'll discard the last 4 chars.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the for loop, you're passing in a string, then iterating over the characters, and returning the first character without the first character, hence an empty string.

```
def clean_string(url):
    return url[:-1]
```

Although I'm not sure you'd still need a function to do this.

If you're just trying to remove the trailing slash, you may prefer to use `rstrip`

```
return url.rstrip("/")
```

Comment: Perfect! I do need a function because I need to apply it to pandas df. This works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your column `key` contains all values of `str` type, and you would like to apply (or rather, `map`) the function to the column, you could simply use `rstrip` (or just `strip`) without defining a function.

Suppose your given pandas dataframe is named as `df`, try:

```py
new_keys = df['keys'].str.rstrip('/')
```

The `new_keys` is a pandas series.